# Spring and @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to build a console application with Spring framework.

I have a class annotated by `@SpringBootApplication`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LoaderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoaderApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And class annotated by `@Component`

```
@Component
public class ElasticLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    // Elastic properties
    @Value("${elasticTransportAddress:#{null}}")
    private String elasticTransportAddress;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticLoader.class);

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg) throws Exception {
        if (!( elasticTransportAddress != null && elasticTransportAddress.isEmpty() )) {
            log.error("[elasticTransportAddress] is not defined in property file");
            return;
        }
        log.info("-> ElasticLoader.run");
    }
}
```

As you can see, at this class I’m trying inject property `elasticTransportAddress` value by `@Value` annotation, but after running my application I can see that property `elasticTransportAddress` stays unassigned.

What did I miss?

Let me to add some notes:

I want to use my application with different property files. For this case I've created `xml-context-config.xml` with such content:

```
    <beans profile="companies">
    <!-- allows for ${} replacement in the spring xml configuration from the
        application-default.properties, application-dev files on the classpath -->
    <context:property-placeholder
            location="classpath:companies.properties"
            ignore-unresolvable="true" />

    <!-- scans for annotated classes in the com.env.dev package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.alexeyzhulin" />
</beans>
```

and use configuration file `companies.properties` which I placed in

[image]

My run configuration with the described profile:

[image]

And this profile is enabled, as I could see in the application logs:

```
2017-01-15 00:10:39.697  INFO 10120 --- [           main] ru.alexeyzhulin.LoaderApplication        : The following profiles are active: companies
```

But when I define properties in `application.properties` and use default profile, the property `elasticTransportAddress` becomes assigned.

Comment: is your ElasticLoader class defined as spring bean?

Comment: No it is not. Could you give me example how can do that?

Comment: @SasiKathimanda, if it's annotated as `@Component`, then it's should be a spring bean...

Comment: yep, realised it . thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rename companies.properties to application-companies.properties. [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) to documentation

Comment: OMG, It works. But why cannot name my property file as I wish, but with special pattern `application-XXX.propreties`? Where I can read about it? Thanks BTW

Comment: You can read about this in Spring documentation [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in the `if` condition. 
This:

```
if (!( elasticTransportAddress != null && elasticTransportAddress.isEmpty() ))
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if (elasticTransportAddress == null || !elasticTransportAddress.isEmpty())
```

Thus, you get the error log message + return in TWO cases:

1. If the property is not defined OR
2. If the property *is defined* and it's value is non-empty.

The fix is to rewrite the `if` condition, e.g.

```
if (elasticTransportAddress == null || elasticTransportAddress.isEmpty())
```

---

*Update 1:* You of course need to make sure this value is *really* defined in application properties.

---

*Update 2:* Your `xml-context-config.xml` file isn't used by Spring at all. 
The recommended way is to use annotation-based configuration with `@SpringBootApplication`. You can do this by *deleting `xml-context-config.xml` completely* and *creating a class annotated with @Configuration*. This configuration-class can include annotations which define *property sources*. E.g.:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("companies")
@PropertySource("classpath:companies.properties")
public final class LoaderApplication {
}
```

Note that you *don't* need to explicitly enable `@ComponentScan` if you use `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: But with condition `if ( elasticTransportAddress == null ) ` I got the same result

Comment: ok; where did you define the actual property? 
(see [document describing order of sources for properties search](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html))

Comment: I've modified my question. It seems that property in default application.properties file works fine but in another file doesn't

Comment: @AlexZhulin, the problem is your `xml-context-config.xml` wasn't considered by Spring at all.

Comment: See the last update on how to achieve what you want with annotation-based configuration (which is the easier and the recommended way). It is possible to go with XML-based config, but it will require a `@Configuration`-annotated class anyway, so the above is really easier.

Answer (score 1):

As the other @Alex said, you have to tell Spring from where you want to retrieve those properties. What you are missing here is another configuration and in your case (Annotation based configuration) you have to add this class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getCompanyConfigurer() throws IOException {

        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("classpath:companies.properties"));
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);

        return configurer;
    }

}
```

---

*Update:*

If you are using the XML based configuration you have to tell Spring Boot what is the XML configuration deleting your annotation @SpringBootApplication in LoaderApplication and adding the XML to SpringApplication in this way:

```
SpringApplication.run("classpath:application-configuration.x‌​ml", args);
```

Finally add this line to the xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" location="classpath:companies.properties"/>
```

And, that's it, hope it helped.